# Jupyter Notebook doesn't shows files and folders in Desktop

Tags: jupyter-notebook

Jupyter Notebook does not show the content(files and folders) of the directory Desktop. However, it shows all files and folders of other directory likes Documents, Downloads etc.
[Screenshot of Jupyter Notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVBF6.png)

I tried:

1. Restarting Jupyter Notebook.
2. Updating Jupyter Notebook, IPython.

Comment: Can you create a notebook in Desktop? Then try running `import os` then `os.getcwd()`. Is the path displayed the path you are expecting?

Comment: Thank You, Now I figured out where I was wrong.

Comment: @NischalLalShrestha can you share what you found out? my jupyter notebook suddenly encountered the same problem

Comment: @IanS The problem/confusion was "My Desktop folder was inside the Onedrive directory"

Answer (score 0):

It could be because your Desktop folder is under Onedrive.

> Go to Onedrive folder > right click Desktop > Properties > Location >
> Restore Default > Yes > Yes

This worked for me.